# OR conditional in loop with Java

Tags: java, loops, boolean

I've got a problem which I don't understand at all.

```
public int test213() {
    int i = 0;
    // for (i = i; i < 8 || i < 6; i++);
    while (i < 8 || i != 6){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

This returns 8, anyone know why?

Comment: Because 6 is less than 8.

Comment: What value did you expect and why?

Comment: I expected it to stop at 6 because i thought that if either of the conditions were false the loop would stop, I assume this isn't the case?

Comment: The already posted answers should be enough for you to understand.

Comment: Read about [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) if you will.

Comment: That's quite helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step through the loop:

```
i = 0. Is i < 8? Yes. Is i != 6? Yes. Is either or both of these yes? Yes.
i = 1. Is i < 8? Yes. Is i != 6? Yes. Is either or both of these yes? Yes.
i = 2. Is i < 8? Yes. Is i != 6? Yes. Is either or both of these yes? Yes.
i = 3. Is i < 8? Yes. Is i != 6? Yes. Is either or both of these yes? Yes.
i = 4. Is i < 8? Yes. Is i != 6? Yes. Is either or both of these yes? Yes.
i = 5. Is i < 8? Yes. Is i != 6? Yes. Is either or both of these yes? Yes.
i = 6. Is i < 8? Yes. Is i != 6? No.  Is either or both of these yes? Yes.
i = 7. Is i < 8? Yes. Is i != 6? Yes. Is either or both of these yes? Yes.
i = 8. Is i < 8? No.  Is i != 6? No.  Is either or both of these yes? No, end the loop
```

So `i` ends up as 8 after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

When `i` reaches 6, `i < 8 || i != 6` is still `true` because `i < 8` (in fact, `i != 6` is not even evaluated in that case), so the loop only exists when `i` reaches 8.

If you had a `&&` instead of a `||`, it would exit when `i` reaches 6.

Answer (score 0):

The i != 6 is irrelevant because of the or (||).  i < 8 always will be true until i = 8.  So that's why it's 8.  It increments up to 8 then kicks out of the loop and returns 8.